# Was revenge downvoted, but only got 50% of the rep back on the auto-calc

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Two days ago I made a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212542/are-automatic-properties-for-private-variables-unecessary/11212586#comment14722911_11212586) to user [ZnArK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1440715/znark) and I am quite sure he took it unkindly and a few minutes later revenge-downvoted me.  (he also has [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11212583/189950) that he has since deleted that perhaps added to his pique)  Frankly, I stand by my comment, but as you can see below, the auto-calc has only restored 3 out of the 6 answers that were clearly the product of this spree.

[image]

Would it be possible to verify that this run of downvotes did in fact happen by the same person?  And if so, would it be possible to clean up the remaining three downvotes?

Comment: Your comments weren't even that bad. It's not like you were rude or out of line... in fact, it looks like you're trying to be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Undownvote** means that the user reversed his votes *manually*.

If serially voting gets reversed, it explicitly says **Serial downvoting reversed**:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That's great to know...but it doesn't answer my essential question -- I believe all 6 to have been a product of revenge downvoting.  Is it possible for all six to be nullified (by either the OP or SO)?  (hmm, the other 3 have since been nullified, yay! ;) )

Comment: Looks like they have been reversed 5 minutes ago.

Comment: Yep, just noticed that myself. :)

Comment: Hmm... i do remember this image :) nice example

Comment: @Lucifer: Only recent (wording has changed) screenshot I could find. Users only seem to post on Meta if the serial downvoting did **not** get reversed or if serial **upvoting** gets reversed. Wonder why that is...